# What is the correct article when talking about sorting, "the order", "an order", or no article?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I write a paper about CSS and there is a following fragment:

> When appropriate, alphabetize shorthand component values.
>
> **The** order in which the component values of a particular shorthand may
> appear is defined by its formal syntax.
>
> ```
> /* font-style, font-variant, and font-weight may appear in any order,
> and they are all omissible, but if present, they must precede
> font-size and font-family, which are both required and must appear in
> that order */
> font: italic small-caps bold 12px/18px serif;
> ```

The subject of my interest is the second sentence. Specifically, the article in the very beginning.

On the one hand, the order in which component values may appear may differ (e.g., `italic` after `small caps`). On the other hand, these variations are limited.

So my question: Which article should be used in the beginning of the second sentence? *The*, *An*, or none (since the noun *order* is uncountable)?

Comment: The order is defined, so there is only one order.

Comment: @WeatherVane But there are actually possible multiple orders. (Yes I know it is ungrammatical to put "s" here.)

Comment: It is **the**. **The** order . . . is defined as...

Comment: [Not I write a paper. In English, we say here: I'm writing a paper. Simple present: I write a paper every semester for this class.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite article, 'the', is used for something *specific*. You are referring to a specific order, so you should use it.

The fact that there are multiple possible orders is irrelevant - once you have narrowed it down to a specific example, it is definite.

For example:

> I'm going to tell you about **a** man I know. You may also know **the** man I'm going to talk about it.

In this example, I used both the indefinite and the definite article about the same subject. The first time, I was referring to him as one among many. I know many men, he is just one. But, once I have highlighted that I am only going to talk about one man, he is *the* man I am speaking about.